# subplot projection overwrites tick_params

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy

I try to plot an image using the coordinates provided by a fits header and obtained by astropy's WCS.

```
from astropy import wcs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
hdr = r[1].header #r ist the repsective fits files, I copied content "w" at the end of the page
w = wcs.WCS(hdr)
ax = plt.subplot(projection=w)
ax.imshow(np.ones((100,100)),origin='lower')

ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize='large',width=25)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize='large')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot with preoction on]

as one can see the tick_params are ignored.

wenn I do the same, but turn off the projection, i.e.:

```
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.imshow(np.ones((100,100)),origin='lower')

ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize='large',width=25)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize='large')
plt.show()
```

[image: tick_parmas works again]

Tick_params is working again.

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

the WCS is:

```
 print(w)
 WCS Keywords

 Number of WCS axes: 2
 CTYPE : 'RA---TAN'  'DEC--TAN'  
 CRVAL : 266.41798186205955  -29.006968367892327  
 CRPIX : 248.5  340.0  
 NAXIS : 497  680
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WCS projection completely replaces matplotlib axis, see [Ticks, tick labels, and grid lines](https://astropy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.3/visualization/wcsaxes/ticks_labels_grid.html). Hence you cannot use the matplotlib methods anymore, or at least you cannot expect them to have any effect on the actual plot.

Instead it would be required to use the methods of the WCS.
So if

```
ax = plt.subplot(projection=wcs)
```

is a `WCSAxesSubplot`, you may get the x axis as `ax.coords[0]` and the y axis as `ax.coords[1]`. Then you may set the ticklabel size

```
ax.coords[0].set_ticklabel(size="large")
```

and the tick width as

```
ax.coords[0].set_ticks(width=25)
```

The two methods `set_ticklabel` and `set_ticks` are methods of the `astropy.visualization.wcsaxes.coordinate_helpers.CoordinateHelper` class. I'm not sure if there is some complete reference to the available methods, but you may always look into [the source code](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/a52b053dc726df86fb833ba453604f0024c0a96e/astropy/visualization/wcsaxes/coordinate_helpers.py#L337) to check what methods are exposed.

Some complete example (based on [one of the examples](https://astropy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.3/visualization/wcsaxes/index.html) from the documentation):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename

filename = get_pkg_data_filename('galactic_center/gc_msx_e.fits')

hdu = fits.open(filename)[0]
wcs = WCS(hdu.header)

ax = plt.subplot(projection=wcs)

ax.imshow(hdu.data, vmin=-2.e-5, vmax=2.e-4, origin='lower')

ax.coords.grid(True, color='white', ls='solid')
ax.coords[0].set_axislabel('Galactic Longitude')
ax.coords[1].set_axislabel('Galactic Latitude')

ax.coords[0].set_ticks(width=25)
ax.coords[0].set_ticklabel(size="large")

plt.show()
```

[image]